# Getting multiple URLs in Laravel with request segment

Tags: php, laravel, request, segment

First, my coding knowledge is limited and I am a newbie to PHP (please go easy on me).  :-)

I currently have the following code in the  section of layout.blade:

```
@if(Request::segment(1) === 'page1')
```

This code properly gets page1 and assigns different  parameters to this page from the rest of the pages on the website.

However, I want to get and apply this to *multiple URLs* instead of only 'page1."

I have tried:

```
@if(Request::segment(1) === 'page1' || 'page2')
```

But this causes ALL pages to have his  code applied.

I have Googled extensively and can't find the answer to what I think should be a relatively easy question.

I would be most appreciative if someone can point me in the right direction.

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you can explain more context, as this is not something you would normally need to do in a Laravel application

Comment: `@if('page1' === Request::segment(1) || 'page2' === Request::segment(1))` is correct if condition. Your case will fail first check and second check will be "if ('page2')" which transforms into "if (true)" and that is why condition always passes.

Answer (score 0):

[in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) — Checks if a value exists in an array.

```
in_array(mixed $needle, array $haystack, bool $strict = false): bool
```

So in the blade file, you can do the following

```
@if(in_array(request()->segment(1),['page1','page2']))
```

for example,if you want to show button only if segment matches page1 or page2 then

```
@if(in_array(request()->segment(1),['page1','page2']))
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" >Primary</button>
@endif
```

for more reading on blade templates [click here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#if-statements)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried what you said, but received a parsing error message:

syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting elseif (T_ELSEIF) or else (T_ELSE) or endif (T_ENDIF)

The layout is using @else but I don't see T_ELSEIF.

Do I need to change something else?

Comment: @DieselDog .you must close if . exmaple updated in answer

Comment: There is currently already:

@ if

@ else

@ endif

(I added a space so stackoverflow doesn't count as me tagging someone).

So the "@ endif" is already on the page.

Any other ideas?

Sorry for the newbie question.

Comment: ``@if ... [1] @else ... [2] @endif`` place the above code in place of either [1] or [2] as suitable to your case @DieselDog

Comment: @DieselDog  you might need to add more detail what error it throwing and which line of code it throwing error

Comment: I figured out the problem. I was commenting out some code using <!--  --> below the IF statement. Apparently I am not allowed to do that. When I removed the commented text, everything works exactly as it should now. Thank you so much for the help, John.